# How do I ensure the contents of a list will be sorted in alphabetic order when converted to JSON?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I'm working on a Java Springboot application, and have a builder data class that I convert to JSON using objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value). I can see that you can sort the fields in the JSON with the annotations
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true) or @SortNatural but these are class level annotations. I have a field that is a List, which I want the contents of to always be in alphabetic order. These 2 annotations don't seem to work at a field level, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort this list with Collection.sort(list) and then set this list to your pojo and let object mapper to map

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to do it with an annotation on the builder object as I have a lot of lists in my builder class and want to avoid having to call Collection.sort each time I assign something to that field. Perhaps there isn't a way to do that though.

Comment: let me search this for you , if i find any solution i'll say